# Are J.K. Rowling interviews Harry Potter canon? What happens to canon if there's a discrepancy with the book?

Tags: harry-potter, canon, jk-rowling

It seems that a lot of Harry Potter questions (including my last one) are answered based on tidbits of info that J.K. Rowling provided in various interviews.

I have two related questions (I'll post them separately):

**Question #2 of 2.** If there ever is a discrepancy between what JKR states in an interview, and a book, which one is considered canon? Book? JKR? Whatever is later?

(What made me think about this was the whole thing with George Lucas and his multiple layers of canon and the whole "L'État c'est moi" Luis-the-14th schtick he has).

Comment: I have added question that is more generic than this one: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10496/what-is-the-official-position-of-jkr-franchise-on-canonicity-of-facts-in-harry . It's not quite a duplicate, since this covers interviews specifically whereas the other one asks about ANY canon of the franchise

Comment: Darth Lucas: I *am* Star Wars!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether JK Rowling interviews and other sanctioned material (such as Pottermore) is considered canon is going to vary based on the reader. Some readers consider only the books to be canon. Others accept interviews and Pottermore as canon. Some even accept the movies. This is subjective; it's going to vary person to person.

Your second question seems a repeat of your previous question, but there are discrepancies in the books and in the interviews. They're called "Flints" after Slytherin Quidditch Captain Marcus Flint, who was the Slytherin Captain Harry's first year, but showed up in the second book. According to JKR he had to repeat his seventh year. So basically she ret-conned.

Comment: Sorry, #1 and #2 were really 2 parts of the same question, split up for clarity: "1. Does this happen, and 2. if it does, how does it affect canonicity"?

Comment: Also, based on what you said, does that mean that Potter universe, unlike Lucasverse, does NOT have "official" canon concept?

Comment: @Jana See [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9273/how-did-large-universes-keep-track-of-canon-before-the-advent-of-wikis) and its answers for some background on how others manage (or don't manage) canon.  It's entirely possible that JKR doesn't believe in maintaining canon.

Comment: @Keen - sorry for not being precise, I was asking about the **rules** (if any) for HP canon, not how those rules are or can be implemented. It's quite possible that there are no "canon" rules at all, but I was looking for confirmation from JKR/Scholastic/whoever on that.

Comment: @Keen - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10496/what-is-the-official-position-of-jkr-franchise-on-canonicity-of-facts-in-harry

Comment: @Jana I love it when a question inspires other questions. :)

Comment: This is my personal canon preference: I go by a simple rule - if I cannot buy it on Amazon (or your outlet of choice), it is not canon. I shouldn't have to youtube a shakey cam interview from Magic-People-Con 2003 to find out what happened in the story. Write that shit down.