# What is the official position of JKR franchise on "canonicity" of facts in Harry Potter universe?

Tags: harry-potter, canon, jk-rowling

We know that there are multiplicity of different works/sources in Harry Potter Universe:

- HP books 1-7
- Associated JKR books (Beedle the Bard, QTTA, HP Prequel story, Magical Beasts)
- HP Movies 1-7
- JKR interviews
- jkrowling.com information
- Pottermore
- Harry Potter amusement parks
- Possibly, other non-JKR franchise works, though to the best of my knowledge none exist as of now and none are planned.
- assorted fan fiction :)

Given that the universe is pretty big/complex, with many sources, it's not surprising that there already are discrepancies between different sources (the obvious ones between books and movies; ones [between different books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10488/how-did-snape-and-voldemort-fly); and [ones between books and JKR interviews](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10486/was-j-k-rowling-ever-incorrect-misleading-in-her-interviews-answers/10487#10487)).

To manage such discrepancies, other universes frequently employ official or unofficial canon rules (as an example, Star Wars [has multiple layers of canon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/what-is-the-singular-source-of-star-wars-canonization/1809#1809), whereas Dr Who [officially has no canon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9273/how-did-large-universes-keep-track-of-canon-before-the-advent-of-wikis/9280#9280)).

Is there an official position of JKR/Harry Potter franchise on HP Universe canon structure?

NOTE: "No canon" and "No current official position" are two different answers.