# Are the illustrations in Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone Illustrated Edition canon

Tags: harry-potter, canon, illustrated-story

Can we consider the illustrations in the newly released illustrated version of *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* canon? I.e. can we draw conclusions about some events, characters and similar based on the illustrations in the book?

(as a side note - I got the book and it is really fabulous) :)

Here some of the illustrations as requested:

Platform 9 3/4
[image: Platform 9 3/4]

Hagrid's Hut
[image: Hagrid's Hut]

Diagon Alley
[image]

Comment: Can you add an image of the newly released illustrated version, so we can easily see your reference?

Comment: @TylerH all the links I found are of commercial sites selling the book. Linking these might be considered an (unapproved) advertisement.

Comment: @vap78 I think that what TylerH was asking for is an example of a picture that might allow you to draw conclusions about events and characters, as you suggested. You wouldn't have to link to a site that sells the book, just show a picture from it, as is common in many SciFi.SE questions.

Comment: @vap78 Indeed, like Thunderforge said, I meant something like this: http://i.imgur.com/YkTOmpS.jpg not simply a link to an e-commerce site.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To my knowledge (and [the knowledge of the Horde](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10496/what-is-the-official-position-of-jkr-franchise-on-canonicity-of-facts-in-harry)), there is no official canon policy for *Harry Potter*. So really, my only answer can be:

### *[Shrug]*

You could make a good argument for both sides. The illustrations were *not* done by Rowling herself, but by an illustrator named Jim Kay; that alone will make them non-canon in some people's eyes.

However, Rowling has approved of them, both publicly and privately; as [the *Telegraph* reports](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/books/what-to-read/harry-potter-illustrated-jim-kay/):

> Rowling has given it her public seal of approval: "Seeing Jim Kay's illustrations moved me profoundly," she wrote for the dust jacket. "I love his interpretation of Harry Potter's world, and I feel honoured and grateful he has lent his talent to it." She also wrote to Kay privately. "She sent a really lovely letter, and that's the first time it hit me that this was real," he says. "Imagine you’re a vicar and you find a Post-it note from God on your fridge. It was like that."

However, keen-eyed readers will note that Rowling very carefully says that Kay's illustrations are *his* interpretation; you might read that as approving of his illustrations without endorsing them as factual - like if she saw some fanart and said "wow, that's quite good."

*However* however, Kay did seem to go to a lot of effort to be true to the characters; later on in that *Telegraph* article, we read:

> he took photographs of [the child models], in the positions he needed according to his preparatory sketches, and altered their features to fit Rowling’s descriptions.

Personally I wouldn't consider them canon, but in the right situations they might make a good addition to a conversation. But that's just my opinion, and there's enough leeway that you can happily form your own.

Comment: Great, now I'm getting Buzzfeed flashbacks.

Comment: @RogueJedi Sorry; I couldn't resist

Comment: Basically this all sounds like a "no" to me, much like the new "from our own correspondent" stuff on Pottermore.

Comment: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-oX95GP0mBnQ/UxDuQht7k-I/AAAAAAAAQCI/PHH0GN9P7iw/s1600/Colin-Farrell.gif

Comment: @Richard in the absence of an official canon policy, something that is *in* the books (especially with the noted approval of JKR) *has* to be elevated above a flat "non-canon" response, even if you might consider it in some respects disputable. It sounds to me like she might even encourage an a-canonical approach, preferring individuals to bring their own interpretation to the table.

Comment: I believe JKR recently said Pottermore is canon in a Tweet (I took it to mean her own writing, not the features or articles) but she's obviously not completely against canon as an idea.

Comment: @ThruGog Well I found [this tweet](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/615498601809211393) where she argues that the new musical should be considered canon; I'm not entirely sure I'm comfortable saying that she's *declaring* it as canon, though. It reads more like she's trying to inform fan opinions, rather than setting out an explicit policy

Comment: I would rather consider this as "no". I think JKR just wants to avoid having to comply with more restrictions in case she decides to write a prequel/sequel.